# Can't connect to samba server with jcifs

Tags: java, samba, jcifs, cifs

I am trying to copy some files from my local machine to a samba server connected in the same network as my computer with Java.

If I try to login via browser or open it in the Ubuntu network devices folder there is no problem, however via Java I don't seem to be able to successfully login.

Here is my code:

```
public static void function() throws MalformedURLException, SmbException {
    String urlToBackUpFile = "smb://dlink-5e6490//Volume_1/newfolder/file.zip";
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new **NtlmPasswordAuthentication("192.168.1.8", "admin", null);**
    SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(urlToBackUpFile, auth);
    SmbFile dest = new SmbFile("file:///home/username/file.zip");
    dir.copyTo(dest);
}
```

I always get one of two errors.

If I only insert the domain and **null** in the username and password fields, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" jcifs.smb.SmbException: The network name
>   cannot be found.  at
>   jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:957)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.copyTo(SmbFile.java:2304)
>   at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.function(JavaApplication2.java:40)
>   at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:48)
>   Java Result: 1

However, if I try to insert the values **"admin"** to the username and **null** or **""** to the password (there is no password for the admin account) it gives me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure:
>   unknown user name or bad password.
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:406)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:218)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:176)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:911)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:957)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:880)
>   at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.copyTo(SmbFile.java:2303)
>   at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.function(JavaApplication2.java:40)
>   at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:48)
>   Java Result: 1

I tried all kinds of combinations in the NtlmPasswordAuthentication line, such like...

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("192.168.1.8", null, null);
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("192.168.1.8", "admin", null);
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("192.168.1.8", "admin", "");
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("smb://dlink-5e6490/", null, null);
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("smb://dlink-5e6490/", "admin", null);
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("smb://dlink-5e6490/", "admin", "");
```

...but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know where can the problem be?

Comment: have you tried to set the domain ?

Comment: I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!) tutorial in order to create a shared folder but I can't still login. I don't know if this "sets the domain". If it doesn't, can you tell me how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Linux commands in order to accomplish this task:

```
String command = "mount -o password=\"" + serverPassword + "\" -t cifs //192.168.1.8/Volume_1 /mnt/files/";

String[] cmd = {"/bin/bash", "-c", ("echo " + sudoPassword + "| sudo -S " + command)};

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Using sudo this way is not advised, but was the only way I managed to make this to work.